# How to measure length (in pixels) between multiple points on an image

Tags: gimp, image-processing

I have a fairly high resolution map, with a known scale. How to measure the length in pixels between multiple points on an image? Straight line is simple, but how to do it when there are multiple points / not straight line?

*Example:*

This can be reduced to 9 legs to get the total length in pixels.

[image]

I currently use the *measure tool*, which allows for a maximum of two legs only. This gets tedious quickly (write down the pixels, and then sum the total later), when there are a lot of curves in a road.